# Pass Texture to D3D9 Effect for Mesh Object

Tags: c++, directx, textures, hlsl, mesh

I'm trying to set up some DX9 code to render Shaders as I'm looking to delve into them a bit deeper.  I have a very basic shader that compiles and displays fine in FX Composer, but after setting up my code to render in my program, the texture does not display for some reason, the mesh is just a dark grey color.  I'm thinking it may have to do with the way DirectX handles meshes but I'm not too sure.  Here's the relevant snippets of code, and as always, thanks in advance!

.fx file

```
float4x4 world_m    : WORLD;
float4x4 view_m     : VIEW;
float4x4 projection_m   : PROJECTION;

Texture gWorldTexture;

sampler2D image = 
sampler_state
{
    Texture = <gWorldTexture>;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = CLAMP;
    AddressV = CLAMP;
};

struct VertexIn
{
 float4 pos     : POSITION;
 float2 texco    : TEXCOORD;
};

struct VertexOut
{
 float4 pos     : POSITION;
 float2 texco       : TEXCOORD;
};

struct pixelInput
{   
 float2 texco    : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexOut  mainVS(VertexIn input)
{
 VertexOut output = (VertexOut)0;
 float4x4 worldview_m       = mul(world_m, view_m);
 float4x4 worldViewProj_m   = mul(worldview_m, projection_m);
 output.pos = mul( input.pos, worldViewProj_m );
 output.texco = input.texco;
 return output;
}

float4 mainPS(pixelInput input) : COLOR0
{
 return tex2D( image, input.texco );
}

technique technique0 
{
 pass p0 
 {
     VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 mainVS();
     PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 mainPS();
 }
}
```

declarations

```
LPD3DXMESH meshSphere;
IDirect3DTexture9 *texture;
LPD3DXEFFECT effect;
D3DXHANDLE gWorldTexture;
D3DXHANDLE technique;
```

gfx_init function

```
LPD3DXBUFFER errorlog;
D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(d3ddev, "earth.png", &texture);    

D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(d3ddev, "dxtshader.fx", 0, 0,     D3DXSHADER_ENABLE_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY, 0, &effect, &errorlog);

D3DXCreateSphere(d3ddev, 5.0f, 25, 25, &meshSphere, NULL);
```

render_frame function

```
void render_frame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 3.0f, 15.0f),
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    effect->SetMatrix("view_m", &matView);

    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                               D3DXToRadian(45),
                               (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                               1.0f,
                               100.0f);
    effect->SetMatrix("projection_m", &matProjection);

    static float index = 0.0f; index+=0.03f;
    D3DXMATRIX matRotateY;
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, index);
    effect->SetMatrix("world_m", &matRotateY);

    effect->Begin(NULL, NULL);
        effect->BeginPass(0);

        effect->SetTexture("gWorldTexture", texture);
            meshSphere->DrawSubset(0);

        effect->EndPass();
    effect->End();

    d3ddev->EndScene(); 

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just creating the sphere and rendering it without a shader but with a texture?  Does D3DXCreateSphere add texture coordinates?  You might be better off generating the sphere mesh yourself so that you have more control over all the other 'stuff' you might want to attach to the vertices.

Comment: Make sure that you have loaded your texture correctly (error checking), and change your pixel shader to return the texture coordinates instead of a color: return float4( input.texcoo.x, input.texcoo.y, 0, 1 );

Comment: I feared that D3DXCreateSphere did not provide texture coordinates, I guess I was just looking for confirmation.  thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to generate a sphere with texture coords: http://pastebin.com/GZV8mbbC, found via this post: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/629242-d3dxcreatesphere-and-texture/

I reckon that the texture coordinates are most likely your problem.

Comment: you know, it's funny...I started with D3D11 a few days back but gave up after not finding a single, decent article about how to procedurally generate a sphere.  I'm not concerned with geometric mathematics so I decided to go back to DX9 since I've used it in conjunction with ogre previously.  this link is extremely helpful I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Truly the textcoords are not provided at all, there is no vertex declaration of any kind to feed information on the vertex data (for example that you bring the text coordinates to the vertex shader :) )